# What’s the benefits of Asp.net MVC projects precompilation?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

My ASP.NET MVC project is taking more time than usual on the first hit，and it gets better afterwards, but the response goes slow again every next day. so It's a continuous performance issue

I googled the issue and most of the solutions are choosing precompilation during publishing, but Microsoft officials seemly didn’t confirm the operation can result in fast startup time for every request at any time.

So what exactly are the benefits of **ASP.NET MVC Precompilation**? Please advise

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23235890/is-it-possible-to-disable-asp-net-website-sleep-in-iis, if what you're going for is faster responses after long periods of time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can basically find the information here, there is also a fair amount of other relevant information on the advantages

[ASP.NET Web Site Project Precompilation Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398860.aspx)

> Precompiling an ASP.NET Web site project provides the following
>   advantages:
>
> **> Faster initial response time for users, because pages and code files
>   do not have to be compiled the first time that they are requested.
>   This is especially useful on large sites that are frequently updated.**
>
> A means to identify compile-time bugs before users see a site. (You
>   can also accomplish this when you compile a project in Visual Studio.)
>
> The ability to create a compiled version of the site that can be
>   deployed to a production server without source code. This makes sure
>   that that people who have access to the production server will not be
>   able to view the source code.

You can also find similar questions here

[What is the advantage of the ASP.NET precompilation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2027653/what-is-the-advantage-of-the-asp-net-precompilation)

[What effect does the new precompile during publishing option have on MVC4 applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16179519/what-effect-does-the-new-precompile-during-publishing-option-have-on-mvc4-applic)

And some related information here

[Precompiling Your Website (C#)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/older-versions-getting-started/deploying-web-site-projects/precompiling-your-website-cs)

> Because the pages must be automatically compiled when they are first
>   visited, there can be a short but noticeable delay when an ASP.NET
>   page is requested for the first time after being deployed.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed answer, I will apply your advice to my project.